# How to wait for an element after page refresh which was previously present through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

A similar question was asked on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787453/selenium-python-how-to-wait-for-a-page-to-load-after-a-click)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "element_id"))
```

This answer doesn't work because the element already existed in the previous page. I want to be able to wait until the page is done loading and then grab the element.

Comment: can you find another element on the new page and wait for it?

Comment: Does it help if you do a `browser.refresh()` immediately after loading the page?

Comment: If the only problem is that the element was found on a page already you could take the easy way out and simply declare the WebElement as a different variable on each page...

Comment: @A.Feng I have edited out the question heading to reflect your usecase. Feel free to revert back the changes if the edit is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the element existed in the previous page and now you want to grab the element after the page is done loading you can induce *WebDriverWait* initially for the [staleness_of(element)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.staleness_of) then once again for the [element_to_be_clickable(locator)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) and you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.staleness_of(driver.find_element_by_id("element_id"))
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "element_id"))
```

Comment: This is not how you use `staleness_of()`. Your method will introduce a race condition based on whether you find the element before or after the page reloads. You need to find the element and store it in `e`, do the action that causes the page to refresh, and THEN wait for staleness of `e`.

Comment: What? How have I lost the rights to ask questions on SO? I just figure out my own answers instead of asking others.

Comment: ... but none of this has anything to do with why this answer is wrong. I already explained why in my comment... you have no evidence to disprove what I said?

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascriptexecutor if you want to wait for page to load and then execute further steps.This will return "**complete**" only if the page is loaded completely.

```
driver.execute_script("return document.readyState")=="complete"
```

Comment: Selenium already does this by default.... it blocks on page load until readyState = complete.